# NetworkInterface is a Wifi Interface?

Tags: java, wifi

How to find wifi network interface from the returned result of

```
NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
```

Answer (score 1):

That information cannot be obtained using Java. You can only retrieve the interface's name and address(es).

Answer (score 0):

Solution for windows 10 (and probably other platforms):
NetworkInterface.getName() returns a name of pattern <interface type>[<index>], where *interface type* is one of "lo", "wlan", "eth", "ppp", "net". So your interface's name needs to match the regular expression "wlan\d+". 
For searching a wifi adapter among the enumeration NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces() you may also filter by NetworkInterface.isUp(), NetworkInterface.isLoopback() .